# Google picker api not entering the onApiLoad function

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I want to integrate Google drive picker api in my application. But the onload function for the google picker api is not calling. Below is the code of mine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GoogleDriveApi</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<div> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**************************************************************** start of Google api code ************************************************************************************************/
    // The API developer key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
var developerKey = 'AIzaSyAZjLxjshv3FpkLK6517tiZ2nYwt6rJZHk';

// The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
var clientId = '814476538527-pijtu7ck89ofep1j4tqr2j38ltruahtd.apps.googleusercontent.com';

// Scope to use to access user's photos.
var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

var pickerApiLoaded = false;
var oauthToken;

// Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
function onApiLoad() {
    console.log("load function calledd");
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
    gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': onPickerApiLoad });
}

function onAuthApiLoad() {
    console.log("auth api success");
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
        },
        handleAuthResult);
}

function onPickerApiLoad() {
    console.log("picker load");
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    console.log("authressult");
    console.log(authResult);
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
    }
}

// Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
function createPicker() {
    console.log("create picker");
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(google.picker.DocsUploadView()).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// A simple callback implementation.
function pickerCallback(data) {
    var url = 'nothing';
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
    }
    var message = 'You picked: ' + url;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
}



/**************************************************************** end of Google api code ************************************************************************************************/
</script>
```

The above .cshtml page will be called when clicking on a button in the page

```
 $("#button").click(function(){
     window.location.href = "/Contact/GoogleApi";
 });
```

Controller code

```
 public ActionResult GoogleApi(){
      retunr View("GoogleApi");
 }
```

The GoogleApi.cshmtl page is loading but it is not calling in to on `onApiLoad` function. I have set the GooglePickerApi to On. Can any know about what's wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the script:

```
  script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad">
```

in body instead of head worked for me. Don't know the exact reason for this though. Hopefully you may have figured it out by now since the post is around 6 months old. If you now the how these scripts are executed please let me know ! With executed I mean the order of execution !